# Card Layout get the current card string

Tags: java, swing, indexing, layout-manager, cardlayout

i'm using cardlayout in application and want to get the name of the current active card
i tried many methods but with no mean, for example this method seems to be no longer exists

```
panel.getLayout().getActiveItem()
```

also i tried this but it doesn't work too

```
 Panel card = null;
      for (Component comp : cardPanel.getComponents()) {
           if (comp.isVisible()) {
                System.out.println(card.getName());

                    }
                 }
```

for example: the following stamts adds several panels to a card layout, i want to return 1,2,3,4 or 5 of the currently active card:

```
    cardPanel.add(firstP, "1");
    cardPanel.add(secondP, "2");
    cardPanel.add(thirdP, "3");
    cardPanel.add(fourthP, "4");
    cardPanel.add(fifthP, "5");
```

what's the possible ways to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CardLayout` does not expose its own mapping between of components and its keys (here `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`...), so using the layout itself will not reveal how the "cards" are hashed.

If you wish to use the [getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName%28%29) method, remember that you must set this yourself first as the field is not set by default:

```
firstPanel.setName("1");
cardPanel.add(firstPanel, firstPanel.getName());
```

then, using your `for` loop, you will be able to get the current card `String`.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways

- [determine visible JComponent from current card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413251/how-to-get-the-top-card-in-javas-cardlayout)
- `putClientProperty` (`setName`, etc) add listeneing by`AncestorListener` or `HierarchyListener`

code

(Disclaimer, Notice this is only code example with `Thread.sleep(int)`, and works only in this form, there is designedly locked `Event Dispatch Thread`)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;

public class CardlayoutTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel pnlA, pnlB, pnlC;
    public CardLayout card = new CardLayout();

    public CardlayoutTest() {
        EventHandler eventHandle = new EventHandler();
        pnlA = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pnlA.add(new JButton("A"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pnlA.putClientProperty("JPanel", "JPanel_a");
        pnlB = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pnlB.add(new JButton("B"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pnlB.putClientProperty("JPanel", "JPanel_b");
        pnlC = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pnlC.add(new JButton("C"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pnlC.putClientProperty("JPanel", "JPanel_c");
        pnlA.addAncestorListener(eventHandle);
        pnlA.addHierarchyListener(eventHandle);
        pnlB.addAncestorListener(eventHandle);
        pnlB.addHierarchyListener(eventHandle);
        pnlC.addAncestorListener(eventHandle);
        pnlC.addHierarchyListener(eventHandle);
        setLayout(card);
        add(pnlA, "A");
        add(pnlB, "B");//
        add(pnlC, "C");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class EventHandler implements AncestorListener, HierarchyListener {

        @Override
        public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
            JComponent comp2 = event.getComponent();
            String str = (String) comp2.getClientProperty("JPanel");
            System.out.println("ancestorAdded " + str);
        }

        @Override
        public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {
            JComponent comp2 = event.getComponent();
            String str = (String) comp2.getClientProperty("JPanel");
            System.out.println("ancestorMoved " + str);
        }

        @Override
        public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {
            JComponent comp2 = event.getComponent();
            String str = (String) comp2.getClientProperty("JPanel");
            System.out.println("ancestorRemoved " + str);
        }

        @Override
        public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
            JComponent comp2 = (JComponent) e.getComponent();
            String str = (String) comp2.getClientProperty("JPanel");
            System.out.println("hierarchyChanged " + str);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardlayoutTest t = new CardlayoutTest();
        t.setSize(300, 200);
        System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.main()------------------------ FIRST");
        t.card.show(t.getContentPane(), "A");
        t.setVisible(true);
        System.out.print("\n");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.main()------------------------ SECOND");
        t.card.show(t.getContentPane(), "B");
        System.out.print("\n");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.main()------------------------ THIRD");
        t.card.show(t.getContentPane(), "C");
        System.out.print("\n");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.main()------------------------ SECOND");
        t.card.show(t.getContentPane(), "B");
        System.out.print("\n");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.main()------------------------ FIRST");
        t.card.show(t.getContentPane(), "A");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```